# Sort and merge a list of object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pull out the values from a list of objects and push it into an array and then sort it. The logic seems to be working, I can console log the output, but not return it.

```js
const mergeKLists = function(lists) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    for (let node = lists[i]; node; node = node.next) {
        result.push(node.val)
    } 
    }
    console.log(result.sort()) // [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6 ]
    return result.sort() // [ undefined ]
};
```

This is what `lists` looks like

```js
[
  ListNode { val: 1, next: ListNode { val: 4, next: [ListNode] } },
  ListNode { val: 1, next: ListNode { val: 3, next: [ListNode] } },
  ListNode { val: 2, next: ListNode { val: 6, next: null } }
]
```

Comment: how can you tell it's returning `[undefined]` ?

Comment: Because when I press "Run Code" on leetcode (which is where I took the exercise from) it shows me `[ undefined ]`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (I removed types to make it plain JS).

I've defined the sorting logic for the sort function, as the default could lead to unexpected behavior, given that it sorts them as strings:

```
[8, 4, 12].sort() // returns [12, 4, 8]
```

You can see this type of behavior only when using integer numbers bigger than 9.

The way to solve this is to sort defining the specific logic for it:

```
[8, 4, 12].sort((x,y) => x - y) // returns [4, 8, 12]
```

In this case, it compares the pair of items and if the result of the operation is < 0, the item is shifted left. Otherwise, if > 0, it's shifted right.

You can check `sort()` documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
const list = [
  { val: 1, next: { val: 4, next: { val: 15 } } },
  { val: 1, next: { val: 3, next: { val: 4 } } },
  { val: 2, next: { val: 6, next: null } }
];

const mergeKLists = function(lists) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      for (let node = lists[i]; node; node = node.next) {
          result.push(node.val)
      }
    }
    return result.sort((a,b) => a - b) // if you use the default sort, 15 would appear before 2
};

const result = mergeKLists(list);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's an exercise of leetcode. I don't know if it's against the rules to link something in comments but if you want I can link you to the exercise page. It doesn't work there don't know why.

Comment: @speed-o-soundSonic have you tried commenting out the console.log(result.sort()) ? Maybe for some reason that sort returns the list but destroys the original one? that would be weird though...

Comment: Yes I have tried it. I have also tried to sort result before returning it, nothing works.

Comment: @speed-o-soundSonic I think I got it. If you use the default `sort()`, it treats them as a string, so if you have a number bigger than 10, you will face some unexpected issues. That's why you should define the criteria for sorting. Check my updated code.

Comment: It still does not work. I think it might have something to do with the way leetcode runs the code behind the scene. In the Testcase the input I see is `[[1,4,5],[1,3,4],[2,6]]` which is passed on to `lists`. Then there's the function `ListNode` which transforms the elements inside the array into a list of objects. I cannot tamper with the ListNode function cause I cannot even see it.

Comment: ah, got it. then lists is actually a list of lists, it's not exactly what you posted in your question.

Comment: What happens if it's a list of lists? I don't understand why I can still see it in the console but cannot return it.

Comment: I don't know the excecise, but in your example you show an array of objects, and here you mention an array of arrays. The code would look different for each case... and in case you receive a list of objects and you need to merge them, probably you need to return a similar structure, not just an array of values.

Comment: Check if this is what you're looking for: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/discuss/443961/javascript-solution-based-on-merging-two-sorted-lists